# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.... i dont understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, commerce.js

When you click on input range, it says dual-range input Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L64UU.png)

preventDefault@react-dom.development.js:6878handleTouchStart@track.jsx:164callCallback2@react-dom.development.js:4164invokeGuardedCallbackDev@react-dom.development.js:4213invokeGuardedCallback@react-dom.development.js:4277invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@react-dom.development.js:4291executeDispatch@react-dom.development.js:9041processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@react-dom.development.js:9073processDispatchQueue@react-dom.development.js:9086dispatchEventsForPlugins@react-dom.development.js:9097(anonymous)@react-dom.development.js:9288batchedUpdates$1@react-dom.development.js:26140batchedUpdates@react-dom.development.js:3991dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@react-dom.development.js:9287dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay@react-dom.development.js:6465dispatchEvent@react-dom.development.js:6457dispatchDiscreteEvent

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: "*Unable to `preventDefault` inside passive event listener invocation*" - well that error message says it all. Don't use a **passive** event listener if you want to call `preventDefault()`!